# Is there a way to get two parallel lines that won't change the distance in Paper js?

Tags: paperjs

I need to draw two parallel lines that won't change the distance between them regardless of the inclination of the lines.

I think one possibility is by changing the start point of the line B to form a perpendicular line with the line A but I can't find a way to get the coordinates of the start or end point of a line using Path.Line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/nVLNTsMwDH4VK6dWy0rZjU3jxm2HSTtuO4TU0GiZi1KPSUx7d9xG7YAVEOTm+Puz5ZMis0c1Vasdsi2VVrYqmtpWVDPYgIZxaYLxHv3CEdYwh6RmE1gDUqGhcFKRxRTm93DahA2BvEj3QhC84GAMLWnWAL6A8IlXTU+QLQZGLTELFYt5cpenGVVhb7x7w6SzgxuYpLNrpQfxio7/VQnuufwx0PiPWt9F+lXnerpFXCjhEZaGy6ypk36ButvAYIxB7mVY3Yf9bB6QD4Fg3dnri9q2BZ57eDQbRIrxwC0lrw6PmUViDHIht3mu4ePXKH5N8hipE85q9GgZm7VyOGDb7L0Gu3LYj+K/e6kcca2m6+35HQ==) that should help you reach your goal.

```js
const createParallelLines = (start, end, distance) => {
    const line = end - start;

    const leftStart = start + line.rotate(90).normalize(distance / 2);
    const leftEnd = end + line.rotate(90).normalize(distance / 2);
    const rightStart = start + line.rotate(-90).normalize(distance / 2);
    const rightEnd = end + line.rotate(-90).normalize(distance / 2);

    const leftLine = new Path.Line(leftStart, leftEnd);
    const rightLine = new Path.Line(rightStart, rightEnd);

    return [leftLine, rightLine];
};

const [leftLine, rightLine] = createParallelLines(view.center - 100, view.center + 100, 20);
leftLine.selected = true;
rightLine.selected = true;
```